# Manage user role and permission at database level

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an application that manages **user role** and **permission** at application level not database level.

Different Tables for explaination :

1. User Table(Contains User details).
2. UserRoles Table(Defines UserRoels).
3. UserRole_Permission Table(Defines permission for each userrole).
4. User_userrole Table(Contains role of each user).(each user can only have one role)
5. Branch Table(Contains branch details).
6. Contract Table(Contains contract details).

[image]

I am using EntityFramework currently, So in order to perform any action say for example branch delete(branch_del) I check whether role to which this user is associated has permission to perform such action or not,as for below table Raj has permission but not Jay. This whole process is performed at application level(back-end) for now.

My question is how can I replicate same on database level in order to support back-end so that user should only be able to perform action for which they have permission else it should give error.

Comment: Do you mean to restrict the 'DELETE..' SQL command when someone logs in directly to your database and issues the command?

Comment: @Thangadurai yes exactly.

Comment: It will be little tricky to do it. May be you can have triggers for each DML command and perform the check within the trigger. I am sure it will not as easy as you think.